# Opportunity Amount - Formula field not displaying currency

Tags: currency

We have a custom object and in that custom object, we have a formula field, which will display the opportunity amount... (Formula field return type is Currency)
Opportunity__r.Amount

In the opportunity record the Amount is displayed in the below format:

```
Oppty currency Amount (User currency)
e.g: CAD xxx (USD xxxx)
```

Whereas in this formula field in the custom object, it just displays the user currency..in the below format

```
User Currency Amount
e.g:USD xxxxx
```

This is the case when opportunity owner view this record. If someone else views this custom object record, then displays the formula field in the below format:

```
OpptyOwnerCurrency Amount (Logged in user currency)
```

It is NOT considering the opportunity currency.

I want to show this formula field in the same format as the opportunity amount field:

```
CAD xxx (USD xxxx)
```

please suggest any workarounds for this issue..

Advanced Currency Management is *not* enabled.

Comment: Do you have Advanced Currency Management enabled?

Comment: No..not at this point...

Comment: I my original post i meant to say that the system is "NOT considering the opportunity currency"...It was a typo error..My apologies..

Answer (score 2):

Once multi-currency is enabled in your org, most objects in the database now have a CurrencyIsoCode field on them. Just because objects like the Opportunity object and your custom object are related by a lookup or master-detail, does not mean that the CurrencyIsoCode codes will be the same. These are separate records in the database, with separate CurrencyIsoCode fields. It sounds like your custom object record has a CurrencyIsoCode in USD. If you change it to CAD, then it will render the currency field in the same format as your Opportunity.

You might consider a Visualforce page for the new and edit screen of your custom object if you need to keep the currency sync'ed to your Opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this formula before.

```
IF( 
  someCurrencyField__c >= 1000000, 
  TEXT(FLOOR(someCurrencyField__c / 1000000)) & ",", 
  "") & 
IF( 
  someCurrencyField__c >= 1000, 
  RIGHT(TEXT(FLOOR(someCurrencyField__c / 1000)), 3) & ",", 
  "") & 
RIGHT(TEXT(FLOOR(someCurrencyField__c)), 3) & "." & 
IF( 
  MOD(someCurrencyField__c , 1) * 100 < 10, 
  "0" & TEXT(ROUND(MOD(someCurrencyField__c , 1), 2) * 100), 
  TEXT(MIN(ROUND(MOD(someCurrencyField__c , 1), 2) * 100, 99)) 
)
```

This approach actually uses a TEXT formula so that you have control over how the numbers are displayed on your custom object.

For more detail, I got it from an Appirio [blog post](http://appirio.com/category/tech-blog/2010/02/displaying-currencies-in-a-sfdc-formula-field-or-visualforce/) originally.